# Vimception: Why does reading the output of executing the current file cause recursion?

Tags: command-line

## Preface:

I first encountered this with a Node.js script I was trying to simulate a REPL with. I cooked up this demo to prove that is also happens with bash.

## Please explain:

Why is it that on subsequent runs of step 9, you get more than just 5 comments?

#### Note:

- The lines that begin with `:` like are intended to be copy-pasted
- You can download a copy of the code below via:

`curl -O https://gist.githubusercontent.com/RichardBronosky/6f936021ed77e77377729d9ed2d1a1f4/raw/vimception.sh`

## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo '##  1. Save this file as vimception.sh                                                                 '
echo '##       :w vimception.sh                                                                              '
echo '##  2. Make it executable                                                                              '
echo '##       :!chmod +x %                                                                                  '
echo '##  3. At the EOF ($), read (r) the result of executing (!) the path (./) to this file (%)             '
echo '##       :$r!./%                                                                                       '
echo '##  4. Run that a few times and watch the comments stack up (colon followed by up arrow is your friend)'
echo "##  5. See the time $(date '+%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M.%S') and [Sub-]Process ID $(sh -c 'echo $PPID') of each run"
      ##  (Okay, enough with echoing the comments!)
      ##  6. Now we'll make this script clean up after itself
      ## 7a. At the EOF ($), put (put) 2 # chars (='##') (This prevents errors by insuring at least 1 match for...)
      ## 7b. separate command (|) globally (g), where pattern (/^##/) matches, delete the line (d)
      ##       :$put ='##'|g/^##/d
      ##  8. Run that a few times to confirm it is idempotent
      ##  9. Combine steps 7 & 3 to get a fresh set of comments rather an seeing them stack up
      ##       :$put ='##'|g/^##/d|$r!./%
      ## 10. Run that one more time
      ## 11. Explain to me what happened
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand, but maybe your issue comes from the global command which doesn't interpret the pipe character as command termination but as a part of its argument. So, when you execute this command:

```
:$put ='##'|g/^##/d|$r!./%
```

Maybe you think it does 3 things:

```
$put ='##'
g/^##/d
$r!./%
```

But in fact, it does only 2 things:

```
$put='##'
g/^##/d|$r!./%
```

In the last command, whenever the global command `:g` finds a line which begins with 2 number sign characters (`#`), it executes this command:

```
d|$r!./%
```

Which means, it deletes the line and it inserts the output of the shell commands (`echo`) contained in your current script.

If you don't want `:g` to interpret the pipe as a part of its argument, you could hide it, wrapping the command in a string and executing it:

```
:$put ='##'|exe 'g/^##/d'|$r!./%
```

This time, `:g` will only see what's inside the string (`d`), it won't execute your shell script every time it finds a line beginning with `##`.

---

I could be wrong, but I think most Ex commands interpret the pipe as command termination. However there are some exceptions, `:g` is only one of them. I think the following ones also interpret the pipe as a part of their argument:

```
:argdo, :bufdo, :tabdo, :windo
:autocmd
:command
:function
:[v]global
:make
:normal
:!
```

I don't remember where I found this list, maybe in the help or in a blog post. There may be other commands which I missed.

Another way of executing a new Ex command after one of these commands, is to type `C-v C-j`, which should insert a newline or a null character.

So, you have 2 choices:

```
:{1st command} C-v C-j {2nd command}
```

or

```
:execute '{1st command}' | {2nd command}
```

---

Edit: I think I found the complete list of commands, it's in `:h :bar`:

```
                            *:bar* *:\bar*
'|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.

These commands see the '|' as their argument, and can therefore not be
followed by another Vim command:
    :argdo
    :autocmd
    :bufdo
    :cdo
    :cfdo
    :command
    :cscope
    :debug
    :folddoopen
    :folddoclosed
    :function
    :global
    :help
    :helpfind
    :lcscope
    :ldo
    :lfdo
    :make
    :normal
    :perl
    :perldo
    :promptfind
    :promptrepl
    :pyfile
    :python
    :registers
    :read !
    :scscope
    :sign
    :tcl
    :tcldo
    :tclfile
    :vglobal
    :windo
    :write !
    :[range]!
    a user defined command without the "-bar" argument |:command|
```

Comment: Wow! That was exactly it. I even read `:help global` to know how to explain `g/` in the comments. I still had no idea that was the issue. Thanks for the excellent explanation in such a short time!

Comment: So, for the real use case (node.js) that had me create this, I used `$put ='//'|exe 'g?^//?d'|w|r!./%` The main difference being the addition of a `w` for writing the file, and use of `//` comments. I really like this pattern of editing in a single window rather than monkeying with `tmux`.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky Nice! Yes, I think it's a common pitfall in Vim, you have to be aware that not all Ex commands treat the pipe exactly the same way.